# Responsive PhotoSwipe with large controls on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

In this official codepen, on my mobile device the controls and caption look very small: 
http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM

I tried adding this to the HTML but it didn't make any difference:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
```

How can I make them larger like in the photoswipe.com site?

Answer (score 3):

If your markup looks like suggested on the PhotoSwipe website and that CodePen you can simply add any HTML elements you like in the `figcaption` element like so:

```
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="img/dektop/1.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1200x1202">
            <img src="img/thumb/1.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
        </a>
            <figcaption itemprop="caption img-description">
            <div class="index">
                <div class="img-title">
                    Title of the image or photo
                </div>
                <div class="img-year">
                    2003
                </div>
                <div class="dimensions">
                    1200 x 900 cm
                </div>
                <div class="technique">
                    Oil on cotton
                </div>
            </div>
            </figcaption>
    </figure>
```

and then use following CSS to style the caption for example:

```
.img-title {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.img-year {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.dimensions {
    font-size: 1em;
}

.technique {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Then you can also add media-queries to the style classes of the caption for mobile and tablet for example if you are not happy with the default values.

```
@media screen and (min-width:0px) {
    .img-title {
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    .img-year {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    .dimensions {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .technique {
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }              
}


@media screen and (min-width:320px) {
    .img-title {
        font-size: 4em;
    }

    .img-year {
        font-size: 2.2em;
    }

    .dimensions {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .technique {
        font-size: 1.1em;
    }              
}
```

**Remember to include all JS and CSS files** like shown here:
http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html

```
<!-- Core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/photoswipe.css"> 

<!-- Skin CSS file (styling of UI - buttons, caption, etc.)
     In the folder of skin CSS file there are also:
     - .png and .svg icons sprite, 
     - preloader.gif (for browsers that do not support CSS animations) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/default-skin/default-skin.css"> 

<!-- Core JS file -->
<script src="path/to/photoswipe.min.js"></script> 

<!-- UI JS file -->
<script src="path/to/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js"></script>
```

I also came across this question [PhotoSwipe: edit parseThumbnailElements function to parse additional markup element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526838/photoswipe-edit-parsethumbnailelements-function-to-parse-additional-markup-elem) and am linking it for you to see how one can build a responsive gallery grid with the PhotoSwipe items and this exact HTML markup that is also used in the CodePen you linked in your question.